# warning: illegal conversion of pointer to integer with char and structure to string

Tags: c, microcontroller, mplab

I have a really annoying problem...

I have to be able to display some text from a structure onto an LCD display from micro controller.

These are the affected areas:

```
struct menu_id {
    char id;
    char menu[11];
    char submenu;
};

void main (void){
    struct menu_id mainmenu[5] = {
    {0, "CHNL1", 1},
{0, "CHNL2", 2},
{0, "Mal Codes", 3},

{1, "CHNL1...", 0},
{2, "CHNL2...", 0},
};

    print(mainmenu[0].id, mainmenu[0].menu);
}

void print (char line1, char line2)
{
    char temp[11];

    LCD_Register_Com();                                                      //Set to Command Register
    OutputChar(LCD_Line0);                                                  //Line 0,0
    LCD_Register_Data();                                                    //Set to Data Register
    sprintf(temp, "%c", line1);
    OutputString(temp);

    LCD_Register_Com();                                                     //Set to Command Register
    OutputChar(LCD_Line1);                                                  //Line 1,0
    LCD_Register_Data();                                                    //Set to Data Register
    sprintf(temp, "%c", line2);
    OutputString(temp);
}
```

Everytime I try to build the code it throws up this error Main_Test.c:108: warning: illegal conversion of pointer to integer for when I call the print function, "print(mainmenu[0].id, mainmenu[0].menu);".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void print (char line1, char line2)
```

change to

```
void print (char line1, char* line2)
```

and

```
sprintf(temp, "%c", line2);
```

to

```
sprintf(temp, "%s", line2);
```

With

```
mainmenu[0].menu
```

You are passing a string not a char to the function.

```
struct menu_id {
    char id;
    char menu[11];  <- string
   char submenu;
};
```

Comment: +1 The fact that it says "pointer to integer", not "pointer to char", suggests that the prototype is missing, too, but this is definitely the main issue here.

Comment: Hey thanks that helped on the build and clean front. The prototype is declared. I should have included that with my question sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

In your function declaration `void print (char line1, char line2)`, `line2` should be of type `char *` as menu is a character array